# In erlang, how do you "list comprehend" the manipulation of deeply nested records?

Tags: erlang, nested, record, list-comprehension, records

I found myself in the position of needing to increment a value which was deeply nested in a series of erlang records.  My first attempts at doing this with list comprehensions were dismal failures.  Originally, the list contained a number of records where the target value would be absent because the record that contained it would, at some level, be undefined.

I dealt with that easily enough by using lists:partition to filter out only those entries that actually needed incrementing, but I was still unable to come up with a list comprehension that would do such a simple operation.

The code sample below probably doesn't compile - it is simply to demonstrate what I was trying to accomplish.  I put the "case (blah) of undefined" sections to illustrate my original problem:

```
-record(l3, {key, value}).
-record(l2, {foo, bar, a_thing_of_type_l3}).
-record(l1, {foo, bar, a_thing_of_type_l2}).

increment_values_recursive([], Acc
increment_values_recursive([L1 | L1s], Acc) ->
    case L1#l1.a_thing_of_type_l2 of
        undefined -> NewRecord = L1;
        L2        ->
            case L2#l2.a_thing_of_type_l3 of
                undefined    -> NewRecord = L2;
                {Key, Value} ->
                    NewRecord = L1#l1{l2 = L2#l2{l3 = {Key, Value + 1}}}
            end
    end,

    increment_values_recursive(L1s, [NewRecord | Acc]).

increment_values(L1s) ->
    lists:reverse(increment_values_recursive(L1s, [])).

........

NewList = increment_values(OldList).
```

That was what I started with, but I'd be happy to see a list comprehension that would process this when the list didn't have to check for undefined members.  Something like this, really:

```
increment_values_recursive([], Acc
increment_values_recursive([L1 | L1s], Acc) ->
    %I'm VERY SURE that this doesn't actually compile:
    #l1{l2 = #l2{l3 = #l3{_Key, Value} = L3} = L2} = L1, 
    %same here:
    NewRecord = L1#l1{l2=L2#l2{l3=L3#l3{value = Value+1}}},  
    increment_values_recursive(L1s, [NewRecord | Acc]).

increment_values(L1s) ->
    lists:reverse(increment_values_recursive(L1s, [])).
```

AKA:

```
typedef struct { int key, value; } l3;
typedef struct { int foo, bar; l3 m_l3 } l2;
typedef struct { int foo, bar; l2 m_l2 } l1;

for (int i=0; i<NUM_IN_LIST; i++)
{
    objs[i].m_l2.m_l3.value++;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not as hard as it seems. @Peer Stritzinger gave a good answer, but here is my take, with a clean list comprehension:

```
-record(l3, {key, value}).
-record(l2, {foo=foo, bar=bar, al3}).
-record(l1, {foo=foo, bar=bar, al2}).

increment(#l1{al2 = Al2}=L1) -> L1#l1{al2 = increment(Al2)};
increment(#l2{al3 = Al3}=L2) -> L2#l2{al3 = increment(Al3)};
increment(#l3{value = V}=L3) -> L3#l3{value = V + 1}.

test() ->
  List =
    [ #l1{al2=#l2{al3=#l3{key=0, value = 100}}}
    , #l1{al2=#l2{al3=#l3{key=1, value = 200}}}
    , #l1{al2=#l2{al3=#l3{key=2, value = 300}}}
    , #l1{al2=#l2{al3=#l3{key=3, value = 400}}}],
  [increment(L) || L <- List].
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use a list comprehension and even don't need to filter out records that don't have the nesting.

To avoid readability problems I shortened your record definition.

```
-record(l3, {key, value}).
-record(l2, {foo, bar, al3}).
-record(l1, {foo, bar, al2}).
```

Define a helper function to increment the value:

```
inc_value(#l1{al2=#l2{al3=#l3{value=Value}=L3}=L2}=L1) ->
    L1#l1{al2=L2#l2{al3=L3#l3{value=Value+1}}};
inc_value(R) ->
    R.
```

Note the last clause that maps any other stuff that doesn't match the pattern to itself.

Lets define example records to try this out:

```
1> R=#l1{foo=1, bar=2}.
#l1{foo = 1,bar = 2,al2 = undefined}
```

This is a record that doesn't have the full nesting defined.

```
2>  R1=#l1{foo=1, bar=2, al2=#l2{foo=3, bar=4, al3=#l3{key=mykey, value=10}}}.
#l1{foo = 1,bar = 2,
    al2 = #l2{foo = 3,bar = 4,
              al3 = #l3{key = mykey,value = 10}}}
```

Another one that has the full structure.

Try out the helper function:

```
4> inc_value(R). 
#l1{foo = 1,bar = 2,al2 = undefined}
```

It leaves alone the not fully nested record.

```
3> inc_value(R1).
#l1{foo = 1,bar = 2,
    al2 = #l2{foo = 3,bar = 4,
              al3 = #l3{key = mykey,value = 11}}}
```

It increments the fully nested record ok.

Now the list comprehension is simple and readable:

```
5> [ inc_value(X) || X <- [R, R1] ].
[#l1{foo = 1,bar = 2,al2 = undefined},
 #l1{foo = 1,bar = 2,
     al2 = #l2{foo = 3,bar = 4,
               al3 = #l3{key = mykey,value = 11}}}]
```

Answer (score 2):

This is *waaaay* messier than it would be in a language with destructive mutation, but it is definitely possible.  Here's the dirt:

```
increment(Records) ->
    [L1#l1{l2 = (L1#l1.l2)#l2{l3 = ((L1#l1.l2)#l2.l3)#l3{value = ((L1#l1.l2)#l2.l3)#l3.value + 1}}} || L1 <- Records].
```

As you can see, this is ugly as hell; furthermore, it's difficult to immediately apprehend what this comprehension is doing.  It's straightforward to figure out what's going on, but I'd have a talk with anyone in my shop who wrote something like this.  Much better to simply accumulate and reverse - the Erlang compiler and runtime are very good at optimizing this sort of pattern.

Comment: Using helper functions as @Peer Stritzinger makes this very readable. If you don't want to define a function for it use a fun instead. In this case I don't really see any need to accumulate and reverse.

Comment: You're absolutely correct - with a helper function or two, this becomes both trivial and readable.  I suppose I read more in to the question than was written; here I had assumed that reducing the bindings and function calls to a minimum was a goal.

Answer (score 0):

The best solution is probably to look into the concept of *lenses* in functional programming. A *lens* is a functional getter and setter for mutation of records. Done correctly, you can then write higher-order lenses which *compose* primitive lenses.

The result is that you can construct a mutator for your purpose and then run the mutator through all the records by a comprehension.

It is one of those things I wanna write some day for Erlang but never really got the time to write up :)